# Handling crash dumps from Firefox and Google Chrome

Tags: linux, firefox, google-chrome, xpcom, npapi

I'm developing a cross-platform NPAPI+XPCOM extension for Firefox and Google Chrome (Windows, Linux and Mac). I was wondering if anyone could enlighten me on the best practices of handling component crashes.

As I understand it, currently Mozilla's Crash Reporter submits mini-dumps and crash reports created to Mozilla Dev. I experimented with blocking SIGSEV to Firefox and creating my own core in the plugin code. Although that works just fine, I'm sure I'm not supposed to do that.

And Google Chrome doesn't even seem to create any core dumps! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The firefox crash report database is publicly searchable, so you don't have to do your own handling. If you ask nicely (i.e. prove you're the plugin author) I'm sure they'll even give you the minidumps from your plugin's crashes.

Answer (score 0):

This is awfully late, but yeah, don't do that. You will wind up catching a lot of things that aren't just your plugin, and you will screw up our crash stats. You should be able to find your plugin crashes in [our crash report site](http://crash-stats.mozilla.org/). If you need better reporting, you can file a bug on us and we should be able to help you.